# How to use different Apple IDs for app developing and for personal life?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, iphone-developer-program, apple-id

I'm trying to understand the mechanism behind Apple dev-center.

I'd like to keep my personal ID separated from the professional one as Apple developer. They bound an Apple ID to the user in a Macbook so if I want to make an app with xcode I must create another user with the professional ID? If I understood is there an other way, possibly easier than this?

Something that allows you to use a single ID (and only one user on the macbook with all your private life stuff) but also keep the development profiles obtained with the other ID as Apple developer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can register as many Apple IDs as you like. In Xcode you can also add different accounts to download and maintain the different provisioning profiles.

So the Apple ID you use to register for the Developer Program can be totally different than your usual iCloud account. You can even use another Apple ID to register for iTunes Connect (which is used to publish and manage your apps in iTunes).

Comment: iTunes connect is different from iTunes? A1 is my personal ID, A2 is for pro. If I use A1 for iTunes and my shopping I can also manage my app associated to A2?
What did you mean when you said "accounts" in xcode? IDs or something else?

Comment: Yes you can have multiple Apple IDs configured in Xcode. iTunes Connect as a service that lets you upload your app to the App Store and is independent of iTunes. Please read the Apple Documentation or other resources, it's all there

Comment: @SebastianWramba see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44529953/keep-personal-apple-id-and-developer-apple-id-separate-or-same) question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44529953/keep-personal-apple-id-and-developer-apple-id-separate-or-same

Comment: @SebastianWramba Can I use AppleId 1 to a project A and Apple Id 2 for project B. Here shall I use one Xcode to develop the different app with different Id.